# Сообщение про откат к ревизии в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: дефект, локализация, мобильная-версия

При просмотре в мобильной версии сайта [раздела](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=responses&__=779127883) <kbd>Активность</kbd> → <kbd>Реакции</kbd> → <kbd>Показать правки</kbd>, сообщение об откате к ревизии содержит дефекты:

1. Отсутствует перевод
2. Вместо указания номера ревизии отображается контрольная сумма

[image: откат]